# How can i use my power supply ( 24VDC 5A ) in redundant mode ? I need to design it

Tags: power-supply, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, switch-mode-power-supply, charge

In redundant mode, if one of my power supply goes off or faulty, my standby power supply shall overtake. I am thinking to use SPDT Relay (24VDC) both in Input as well as Output. secondary power supply will be connected to NC pin and the relay will trigger by the output of Power supply 1.

attached is the block diagram.

Is this a right way !
will i get the efficiency !

Kindly suggest a better way to do so.

[image]

Comment: what device are you powering?

Comment: what efficiency are you asking about?

Comment: I will be powering Information Display. efficiency interms like if i used relay for redundancy , will there be any effect on ot. and what will be the response time of any other way of achieving redundancy ?

Comment: What's the hold-up time of your powered circuit?  What kind of failure are you trying to protect against?

Comment: What is going to power your standby supply? (Assuming if the first one goes offline, it is because the mains power has vanished.)  Is the standby supply operated from batteries?

Comment: @vir There is no holdup time, the secondary power supply shall takeover as soon as primary goes off....... primary supply failure.....no output etc

Comment: @rdtsc standby supply will come into play only if primary goes heywire..... input power and output load is common for both. if input goes off, both shutdown.

Comment: I simply use schottky diodes large enough to handle the load, then I feed each power supply through the diode. I adjust the primary for many 100 mv or so above the secondary power supply, the switch over is instantaneous and you can take either offline no problems. it is worth the small amount of heat or you can use P-Channel MOSFETS.

Comment: @Gil indeed diode redundancy is most economical option. But I think its only okay for basic applications.

Comment: Md Adil what is not basic in the description given? If A relay is used he will have to hold up the power until the stand by system takes over.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the right way:

The problem, with the design above is that any supply capacitors in the device being powered must discharge before the relays will activate the secondary power supply.

It may be sufficient to arrange for the relay to de-activate at 23V using a comparitor circuit or by monitoring the feedback channel of the primary power supply.

Also it can't start without the secondary power supply, when the relays switch on the primary supply suddenly has to start the load, typically this is a higher than normal current resulting in a voltage drop and the relays turn off again.

To do this you'll probably need to detect the current out of the main powersupply in addtion to its voltage, as during power on it will likely be under-voltage but supplying a high current.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so to discharge the Primary output capacitor can Breeder be used.

Comment: also why do we need secondary power supply to start ? my power supply comply soft start so there will not be any inrush current hence no voltage drop.

Answer (score 1):

> There is no holdup time, the secondary power supply shall takeover as soon as primary goes off.

No, it won't.  It will take over *after* both relays have activated (which could take over 10 milliseconds), and *after* the secondary power supply starts up (which could be over 1 second if it is a switching supply with power quality monitoring and a soft-start circuit).

For a true backup source with no brown-out or black-out, consider this:

1. Have both supplies connected to the input power source all the time.  This eliminated relay delay and startup delays.
2. Replace the output switching relay with large Schottky diodes.  This eliminates the other relay delay.  Also, DC relay contacts can be unreliable.
3. To make sure one supply is the "primary", adjust its output to be approx. 0.5 V higher than the backup supply.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Those where my initial considerations, to save power i switched of secondary power supply. Diode has some drop, so it effects the overall efficiency. but seems legit, I will make a provision for this too in prototype so that I can match the performance of the two.